# Locate an HTML element inside of the <iframe> by using Xpath (selenium c#)

Tags: c#, selenium

*I am trying to find this element by partial class, the **HTML** code is as following :*

```
<a class="follow-button profile" href="https://twitter.com/123" 
role="button" data-scribe="component:followbutton" title="Follow 123 
on Twitter"><i class="ic-button-bird"></i>Follow</a>
```

*The method I used is as following:*

```
var element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@class, 'follow-button profile')]"));
```

*Any ideas what might be the reason for not being able to locate the element?*

Comment: When you say you cannot find it, what exactly is happening?  Is there an exception being thrown?

Comment: @ Richard Yes indeed, "No such element" exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoSuchElement` exception generally has one of the following causes:

1. Your element is inside a `<frame>` or `<iframe>`.  Examine your HTML for those.

   - If this is the case, you can use `SwitchTo().Frame()`
   - `Frame()` accepts 3 arguments

     - An `IWebElement`

       - `IWebElement frameElement = driver.FindElement(By.Tag("frame"));`
       - `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameElement);`
     - name of `<frame name="MyFrame">` or `<iframe>`

       - `driver.SwitchTo().Frame("MyFrame");`
     - Index of the `<frame>` or `<iframe>`, starting from 0

       - `SwitchTo().Frame(0)`
   - After you finish in the `<frame>` context, you will need to switch back to the correct context

     - `driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();`
2. Your element is loading on the page after Selenium thinks your page has finished loading

   - If this is the case, you can use `Wait` to tell Selenium to pause until the element finishes loading on the page.

```
    public WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(ByLocator));
```

Comment: *Thank you , very well explained,*

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple classes in the element that you are trying to locate. The correct way to use `xpath` in that case is as follows:

```
var element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@class, 'follow-button ') and contains(@class, 'profile')]"));
```

You could also use `css`

```
var element = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".follow-button.profile"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be class value is changing in your case at run time. You can try manually and check this.